# How to assign a copied jira board to project using API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

I'm trying automatize some processes. I create a project using  Jira API and can not find possibilities to change the board's setting using API.
How I am doing it using UI. Firstly I copy the board then I walk to my copied board's settings and change its location to desired project. After that I delete the old board of this project. I did not find any method for assign board's configuration. There are only some API methods for getting configuration not setting. Have you got any suggestions for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there are currently any API methods that would allow you to perform that change. My suggestion would be instead use the [Create](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/api-group-board/#api-rest-agile-1-0-board-post) method to create a new board with the copied configuration, and set the project location during creation.

You could also potentially try use the https://sitename.atlassian.net/rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapidviewconfig/boardLocation PUT method, which is what's called when you change the location from the UI. However that is from the frontend, so your mileage may vary as far as authentication and use in general.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I solved my task according to this topic [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-articles/Jira-Cloud-Automation-Create-a-project-with-shared-settings-from/ba-p/1970419)

Comment: Howevere there are not important things about boards`s owner that need to be replaced  by  /rest/api/3/filter/{filterId}/owner and then we need to send  request for changing permission /rest/api/3/filter/{filterId}/permission